# Computing leading set (compiler design)

Tags: c, parsing

I have written this program to compute the leading set of the following productions

```
E->E+T
E->T
T->T*F
T->F
F->(E)
F->#
```

Here identifier is taken as '#'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
struct leadT
{
    int n;
    char lead[5];
};
struct leadT leading[7];
char ip[7][7];
int col,cnt=0;
char Sym[5]={ '+','(',')','*','#','i' };
int isSym(char);
void findLeading(char,int);
void leadTabOp(char,int);
void main()
{
    int i,j,c;
    char b[4];
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&ip[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
       {    c=0;
        for(j=0;j<i+1;j++)
        {
            if(ip[i][0] == b[j])
            {
                c=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(c !=1)
        {
          b[cnt] = ip[i][0];
          cnt++;
        }

        }   
    for(i=cnt-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   leading[i].n=0;
        col=1;
        leading[i].lead[0]=b[i];
        findLeading(b[i],i);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=leading[i].n;j++)
        {
            if(j==0)
            {
                    printf("leading(%c) = { ",leading[i].lead[j]);
             }
           else if(j == leading[i].n)
           {
               printf("%c ",leading[i].lead[j]);
           }
           else
           {
               printf("%c,",leading[i].lead[j]);
           }

        }
        printf("}");
        printf("\n");
    }

}
int isSym(char ip)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(ip==Sym[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
void findLeading(char p,int row)
{
    int i;
    for(i=5;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(p == ip[i][0])
        {
            if((ip[i][2] == '>') && (ip[i][4]=='\0'))
            {
                if(isupper(ip[i][3]))
                {
                                leadTabOp(ip[i][3],row);
                }
                else
                {
                                leading[row].lead[col]=ip[i][3];
                                leading[row].n++;
                                col++;
                }
            }
            if( (ip[i][2] == '>') && ( isupper(ip[i][3]) ) && ( isSym( ip[i][4] ) ) )
            {
                            leading[row].lead[col]=ip[i][4];
                            col++;
                            leading[row].n++;
            }
            if( ( ip[i][2] == '>') && ( isSym( ip[i][3] ) ) && ( isupper( ip[i][4] ) ) )
            {
                            leading[row].lead[col]=ip[i][3];
                            col++;
                                leading[row].n++;
            }
        }
    }   
}
void leadTabOp(char p,int row)
{   int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
    {
        if(p == leading[i].lead[0])
        {
            for(j=1;j<=leading[i].n;j++)
            {
                leading[row].lead[col]=leading[i].lead[j];
                col++;
                leading[row].n++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please review this.

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your code a bit better and improve your naming conventions.

The first loop in `main()` apparently scans 6 strings into `ip`. From that I might deduce that `ip` is supposed to hold your input. So name it `input` or even `inputProductions`. Current IDEs support code completion so not using longer names for the sake of less typing is not a valid argument.

You could also put that code into a separate function `readInput(char **result)`. Later you can adjust how you read your input without changing `main`.

Then you have a couple of nested loops which compute some values to be stored in `b` and a value `c`. Using `i` and `j` as loop counter is accepted practice so that's ok but what are `b` and `c` supposed to represent? Give them names which express their meaning.

Also your outer loop counter `i` can go up to 5 and `j < i + 1` means `j` can go up to 5 as well. `b` is only an array with 4 elements, so the last index you are allowed to access is 3 and `b[j]` would be out of bounds for any `j > 3`.

If that nested for loop is supposed to do some pre-processing then put it into a function and give it a sensible name which expresses what it is doing.

You have a variable called `cnt` - what exactly is it that you are counting? Name the variable accordingly.

Your functions access global variables like `cnt` or `ip`. You should pass all data those functions require as parameters. There is not need to create implicit dependencies.

Organize your code so its concerns are separated: input parsing, data processing, output. Your `main` function should read something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char input[7][7];
    char b[4];
    int count;

    if (!readInput(input))
    {
         puts("Failed to read input.");
         return -1;
    }

    count = preProcessInput(input, b);
    if (count < 0)
    {
        puts("Failed to pre-process input");
        return -2;
    }

    if (!findLeadingSet(input, b, leadingSet, count))
    {
        puts("Failed to process input");
        return -3;
    }

    printLeadingSet(leadingSet);

    return 0;
}
```

This makes the structure immediately clear and explains what the steps are without having to read all the code and trying to understand it (apparently `preProcessInput` should be named as to what it is actually pre-processing).